# Premade or rough code outline for provably fair system

Tags: random-seed

I'm looking to create a rather simple mystery box for some of my products, but would like to implement a provably fair system (i.e. not just sell on ebay).
I have some knowledge of Java, Javascript and C as well as website hosting, but not really enough to get this done in a clean manner. Are there any templates or similar to get this done nicely?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "provably fair", but if you're looking for a good RNG, you can look at [CSPRNGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically-secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look!
Honestly mostly looking for an easy way to implement without making a website from scratch. I've done some RNG stuff before, but need it to be doable as a plugin. Need the site to look professional.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.